# Utility Test Java

Tags: java

"public static int readInt(String s)"      wat does this exactly do in a program?? Currently i need to use 4 of these but they all different and for the one i showed up here, i need to make a program where the user is prompted something and if the input is an int then it gets displayed and then goes to the second input for the user and if right then goes, but else if not an int; if its a double then print out "This is not valid..." and then will repeat the first one again and will also do the same thing for the second input if the second one prompted by the user is not an integer. There will be a total of two inputs for the user. What should i do to make a program for this? I am confused of how to use this "public static int readInt(String s)".

package rationalnumber;

import java.util.*;

public class Utility
{
    public static int readInt(String s)
    {

```
} 

public static double readDouble(String s)

/**
 * Generates a random integer between min and max, inclusive
 * Precondition: min <= max
 * @param min lower bound for the random integer
 * @param max upper bound for the random integer
 * @return A random integer
 */
public static int randomInt(int min, int max)
{

}

/**
 * Computes the gcd between 2 nonnegative integers
 * Precondition: num1 >= 0, num2 >= 0
 * @param num1 The first integer
 * @param num2 The second integer
 * @return the gcd of num1 and num 2, gcd is 1 if both are 0, 
 *          gcd is the non-zero number if only one is 0.
 */
public static int gcd(int num1, int num2)
{

}
```

this is like part of the code....i also need to add comments on here well so far those are the last two parts of my code but i couldnt start it without the first two parts.

package rationalnumber;

/**
 * Test program for the Utility class
 */
public class UtilityTest 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String prompt1 = "Enter first integer: ";
    String prompt2 = "Enter second integer: ";

    int a = Utility.readInt(prompt1);
    int b = Utility.readInt(prompt2);

    int small = Math.min(a, b);
    int large = Math.max(a, b);

    System.out.println("A few random integers: ");
    System.out.println(Utility.randomInt(small, large));
    System.out.println(Utility.randomInt(small, large));
    System.out.println(Utility.randomInt(small, large));
    System.out.println(Utility.randomInt(small, large));

    System.out.printf("The gcd of %d and %d is ", a, b);
    System.out.println(Utility.gcd(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b)));    
}
```

}

in the end i use this which is in the same program but in another folder to run it.

Comment: Nobody knows what `readInt(String s)` is in your app. You should provide some code to get a help.

Comment: `Java` is not the same as `Javascript`.  This question has nothing to do with `Javascript`.

Comment: Are you writing the program from scratch, or is your teacher giving you a shell?

Comment: He gave us somewhat of a shell.

Comment: Solved it :D thanks guys :D

Answer (score 1):

Break it down:

`Public` -- Signifies this is a public method

`int` -- Signifies that the function will `return` an integer

`readInt` -- Name of the function

`String s` -- Signifies that the function takes a parameter of type `String` that will be referred to as `s` within the function.

Comment: That was helpful but when i make my program...im confused of how to do it. Is it that i used a inpu.next() for wat the user will input? Like wat do i need to do in the program for this one.. cause ive tried to work it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

`Public` --a public method

`int` -- return tpye integer

`readInt` -- **Name of the function that will read a string and return it as an integer.in your program it will read prompt1 and prompt2 , like take input form the user ,  and store them int a and int b.**

`String s -`- Signifies that the function takes a parameter of type String that will be referred to as s within the function.